# Custom duration field on blackberry

Tags: user-interface, blackberry, field

Does anyone have a duration field they have created for Blackberry?  The field needs to allow the user to select days, hours, minutes; needs to build in OS 4.5 and support touch interface manipulation (on the Storms).

Answer (score 1):

You could use some kind of workaround, using a `DateField`.
On a screen, try this

```
  SimpleDateFormat sdF = new SimpleDateFormat("dd:HH:mm");
  DateField hourMin = new DateField("Duration (dd:HH:mm)", 0, sdF);
  hourMin.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
  add(hourMin);
```

SimpleDateFormat and DateField should be both available in 4.5 and capable of handling touch events.